# How do I recover from a drive partition? Which partiton?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, uefi, gpt

*There are no recovery options during boot.  The `control panel` shows system restore options, but no options for recovering Windows itself.*

How do I [recover to reinstall Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options)?

> You can also Recover from a drive. This will reinstall Windows 10
>   (unless your PC came with Windows 8/8.1 and a recovery partition from
>   your PC manufacturer, in which case it'll reinstall the version of
>   Windows that came with your PC). It'll also remove your personal
>   files, apps and drivers you installed, and changes you made to
>   settings.

For Disc 0:

Why is the first recovery partition for disk 0 marked as active?

Why is the last partition in the screenshot **also** marked as a recovery partition?

Why the two recovery partitions?

```
Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.14393.0

Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: BUDDY

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     C   Acer         NTFS   Partition    915 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 1         Recovery     NTFS   Partition    600 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 2         ESP          FAT32  Partition    300 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 3         Push Button  NTFS   Partition     15 GB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 4     D   Transcend    FAT32  Removable    117 GB  Healthy
```

as compared to:

[image]
    DISKPART>

Volume 3 from `list volume` looks to be the actual NTFS recovery partition?

To [reinstall Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options), use the push button to re-install the OS?

Perhaps `recoverydrive.exe` would be of some utility here?